# Returning String from Javascript inside asp.net control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vbscript

I have this javascript function

```
 function getListOfUidMeter(){
    input = "";
    var tbl = document.getElementById('tableStripy'), i;
    for (i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
        input = input + tbl.rows[i].cells[11].outerText).split(",")[0] + ",";
    }
    return input;
}
```

this function return a string

i want get the output of this function inside asp page but i can't figure out how to do it

```vb
<form name="Form1" method="post" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode==13) {this.submit();event.returnValue=false;} else event.returnValue=true;">
<input class="lookup" type=hidden name="Id" value="<%=PageParams1.Id%>">
<input type=hidden name="SessionId" value="<%=PageParams1.SessionId%>">
<input type=hidden name="Command" value="">
<input type=hidden name="AccountID" value="<%=PageParams1.AccountID%>">
<input type=hidden name="UIDFACILITY" value="<%=PageParams1.UIDFACILITY%>">
<input type=hidden name="FACILITYID" value="<%=PageParams1.FACILITYID%>">
<input type=hidden name="METERID" value="<%=PageParams1.METERID%>">
<input type=hidden name="UIDMETER" value="<%=PageParams1.UIDMETER%>">
<input type=hidden name="UIDMeterHistory" value="<%=PageParams1.UIDMeterHistory%>">
<input type=hidden name="CustomerName" value="<%=PageParams1.CustomerName%>">
<input type=hidden name="CustomerId" value="<%=PageParams1.CustomerId%>">
<input type=hidden name="EntityParam" value="<%=PageParams1.EntityParam%>">
<input type=hidden name="SORT_BY" value="<%=PageParams1.SORT_BY%>"> 
<input type=hidden name="SORT_ORDER" value="<%=PageParams1.SORT_ORDER%>">
<input type=hidden name="Mode" value="<%=PageParams1.Mode%>">
    <table class="SnapIn" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border=0><tr class="ToolsTabs">
  <td class="Title"><nobr><%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("MeterHistory")%></nobr></td>
   <td class="ToolsLeft">
    <b><%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("ID")%></b> &nbsp; <%=meterId %>
     <%if (PageParams1.Mode == "ServicePoint") {%>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../../ccs/MainWebPart.aspx?Mode=             

    <%=PageParams1.Mode%>&SessionId=<%=PageParams1.SessionId%>&Uid=  
    <%=Proxy1.Session.GetPropertyValue("SERVICEPOINT_UID")%>">
    <%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("ServicePointSummary")%></a>
    <% } else if (PageParams1.Mode == "MarketParticipant") { %>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../../ccs/MainWebPart.aspx?Mode=
    <%=PageParams1.Mode%>&SessionId=<%=PageParams1.SessionId%>&Uid=
    <%=Proxy1.Session.GetPropertyValue("MARKETPARTICIPANT_UID")%>">   
    <%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("MarketParticipantSummary")%></a>
    <% } %>
  </td>
  <td class="ToolsRight"><nobr>&nbsp;
        <%if (PageParams1.AccountID) {%>
      <b><%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("AccountID")%></b>
      <a class="Link" onclick='window.navigate("../viewaccount/Meters.asp?Id=<%= escape(PageParams1.AccountID)%>&SessionId=<%=PageParams1.SessionId%>")'><u><%=PageParams1.AccountID %></u></a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <%} if (PageParams1.CustomerId) {%>
    <b><%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("CustomerID")%></b>
      <a class='Link' onclick='navigate("../../ccs/MainWebPart.aspx?Id=

    <%=escape(PageParams1.CustomerId)%>&SessionId=<%=PageParams1.SessionId%>"+"&Mode=Customer")'> 
          <%=PageParams1.CustomerId%>
      </a>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <%} if (PageParams1.UIDFACILITY) {%>
        <b><%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("FacilityID")%></b>
        <a class=Link onclick='navigate("../cust_facility/Basics.asp?UIDFACILITY=<%=PageParams1.UIDFACILITY%>&SessionId=<%=PageParams1.SessionId%>&X_ROWPERPAGE=50")'>
            <%=PageParams1.FACILITYID%>
        </a>
      <%}%>
  </nobr></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="TabBox" colspan="3"><%= RenderTabs("MeterRead") %></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="Body" colspan="3">
    <%          if (OperationError) ReportError(OperationError)%>

    <%if (PageParams1.Command=='Edit') { %>
            <table width=100%><tr><td class=LinkBox>
              <%if (Proxy1.Allow("//ACCTMGT/ACCTCOMP/ACCTMET/@UPDATE")) {%>
              <a href="javascript: Save()"><%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("Save")%></a> |
              <%}%>
              <%if (PageParams1.EntityParam && Proxy1.Allow("//ACCTMGT/ACCTCOMP/ACCTMET/@REMOVE") ) { %><a href="javascript: Delete()"><%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("Delete")%></a> |<% } %>
              <a href="javascript: Cancel()"><%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("Cancel")%></a>
            </td></tr></table>
    <%} else%>
        <%=tMeterHistoryTable %>

    <%if (PageParams1.Command != 'Edit') { %>
        <table style="width: expression(Math.max(document.body.offsetWidth-55, 540))">
        <tr>
        <td align=left>
        <%
                    if (Proxy1.Allow("//FACILITY/ADD"))
                    {
                %>
                                <a href="javascript: Edit()" ><%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("Add")%></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <%
                    }
                    if (Proxy1.Allow("//FACILITY/REEST_ACTION/@REESTIMATE")) { %>
                                <a href="javascript: reestimate()">Ristima</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <%
                    }
                    if (Proxy1.Allow("//FACILITY/REEST_ACTION_2")) { %>
                                <a href="javascript: reestimate2()">Ristima lettura conferimento</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <%  }
                    if (Proxy1.Allow("//FACILITY/REEST_ACTION/@DISCHARGE")) { %>
                                <a href="javascript: discharge()">Scarta</a>
                <%  } %>
                            </td>
                            <!--Indicazione righe e pagina-->
                            <td align=right>
                            <%= Paginator_b(PageParams1.ROWPERPAGE, PageParams1.PAGENUMBER) %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
            <%
                } 
            %>
<div class="mAppScroll" style="height:100% width:100%"><% =tTable %></div>
<tr>
                        <td>
                            <!--Cannata Alberto - modifica del 09/10/2006: aggiorniamo i campi LSUSER e LSTIME della METERHISTORY.-->
                            <input type="hidden" name = "OLD_STATUS" value = "<%=oldstatus_str%>">
                            <input type="hidden" name = "X_LSUSER" value = "<%=username_web.toUpperCase()%>">
                            <input type="hidden" name = "X_LSTIME" value = "<%=data_modifica%>">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
</td>
</tr>
</table><!-- /SnapIn -->
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
getListOfUidMeter();
</SCRIPT>
    </form>
    </body></html>
    <% }     
    catch (e) {ReportError(e); } %>
```

I already call the javascript function inside it but how do i get the result to use it inside the asp page?

Comment: where do you want to show this value?

Comment: you want this value be available for you from server side Am I correct?

Comment: yes  want this value be available for you from server side correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve that, however, since you're using hidden fields here is a simple way:

- Add a new hidden field for ex "hfTemp"
- in your `Javascript` function store the returned value in that hidden field.

  $get('hfTemp').value = input
- in Asp.net after calling the JS function, use :

(VB)

```
   Dim JSValue As String = Request.Form("hfTemp")
```

(C#)

```
string JSValue = Request.Form("hfTemp");
```

Comment: i can use vbscript for the same thing?

Comment: sure, you can. it's the same